# How can I implement basic question answering with hugging-face?

Tags: python, pytorch, huggingface-transformers

I have:

```
from transformers import XLNetTokenizer, XLNetForQuestionAnswering
import torch

tokenizer =  XLNetTokenizer.from_pretrained('xlnet-base-cased')
model = XLNetForQuestionAnswering.from_pretrained('xlnet-base-cased')

input_ids = torch.tensor(tokenizer.encode("What is my name?", add_special_tokens=True)).unsqueeze(0)  # Batch size 1
start_positions = torch.tensor([1])
end_positions = torch.tensor([3])
outputs = model(input_ids, start_positions=start_positions, end_positions=end_positions)
loss = outputs[0]

print(outputs)
print(loss)
```

As per the docs. This does something giving:

```
(tensor(2.3008, grad_fn=<DivBackward0>),)
tensor(2.3008, grad_fn=<DivBackward0>)
```

However, I want an actual answer if possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to [Joe Davison](https://twitter.com/joeddav) for providing the answer [on Twitter](https://twitter.com/joeddav/status/1228730564297011201):

```
from transformers import pipeline

qa = pipeline('question-answering')
response = qa(context='I like to eat apples, but hate bananas.',
              question='What do I like?')

print(response)
```

gives a response of:

```
{'score': 0.282511100858045, 'start': 31, 'end': 38, 'answer': 'bananas.'}
```

Not quite right, but at least the score is low.